# Multiply Colume "A" in Dplyr with different numbers based on Colume"B" , to generate a new colume "C"

Tags: r, dplyr

I was trying to  generate a new column "C" by Multiply Column "A"  in Dplyr with different numbers based on Column"B"

I've tried to use If_else function but it does not work for me

```
My Data <- select(A,B)%>%

if_else(B<60,
mutate(VKT_VHT,C=A*3),
mutate(VKT_VHT,C=A*4))

Error: `condition` must be a logical vector, not a 
`spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object
```

Comment: Try `mutate(VKT_VHT, C = if_else(B < 60, A*3, A*4)`

Comment: Hi Sotos, Thank you for helping me. I was wondering what if it's a number from another table instead of "3" and "4"? Can I link another table to the equation?

Comment: Well, that changes things quite a bit. Maybe it's better to ask a new question

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/57179026/680068

Answer (score 1):

```
my_data <- VKT_VHT %>%
    mutate(C = if_else(B<60, A*3, A*4))
```

should work and add column C to your data table.

Comment: couple of things... That is definitely not a `data.table` (most likely a `tibble` due to `dplyr`). Also, `VKT_VHT` is the name of the data frame

Comment: This solution works though? All my dplyr modifications in data tables work like this.

Comment: Yes, they do work on data table as well. My comment was just to clarify (avoid confusion).

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure to be more clear next tim with my answers. I was confused by the top line: ```my data <- select(A,B)%>%```

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit confusing. It looks as like `My Data` is the new data frame they want to create instead of just updating their current one

Comment: Thanks guys, it was really helpful. I will ask another question regarding how to times "A” by a value from other table..